# How do I get locals from a lua script in java

Tags: java, lua, luaj

I have this lua script:

```
local set = {}
set.name = "DebugMenu"
set.setName = "DebugMenu"
set.descriptionFilenameOverride = ""
set.logicalName = "<DebugMenu>"
```

In java I have:

```
LuaValue script = globals.load(..input stream.., "main", "t", globals);
```

How do I access the values in the table in the lua script?

Comment: `local`s are meant to be lexically scoped. You *can* do this with enough debug hackery, but are you sure you can't just make the table a global or parameter to some function instead?

Comment: Can you return `set` in the Lua script?

Comment: I have lots of scripts in this format which I need to get the details from the table from each one from, so not really.

Answer (score 0):

You could rename it `local_set` instead, just so there's no confusion with the half-a-dozen or so other `set` functions (sethook, setmetatable...) that reside in _G.  Then drop that `local`, so you can access contents from global scope.

https://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/debug.getlocal  The possibility exists, but it's wonky.  https://www.lua.org/pil/23.1.1.html  You'd have to scroll through keys 'till you find it.

```
local stack_level = 1
local stack_index = 1

while true do
    local name, value = debug.getlocal( stack_level, stack_index )
    print()
    if not name then break end

    if type( value ) == 'table' then
        for k, v in pairs( value ) do
            print( k, v, type(v) )
        end
    else  --  could be recursive, if you need to dig deeper
        print( name, value, type(value) )
    end

    stack_index = stack_index +1
end
```

---

**Edit:**

Seems easier just to rename it, so it's safely accessible from within your globals.

```
local_set = {}

local_set .name = 'DebugMenu'
local_set .setName = 'DebugMenu'
local_set .descriptionFilenameOverride = ''
local_set .logicalName = '<DebugMenu>'
```

Comment: I need to do this in Java using Luaj, is it possible?